Eigenvectors of the Cold Plasma Dispersion Relationship
I'm currently making my way through the textbook "Introduction to Plasma Physics" by Donald Gurnett. In section 4.4.2: Propagation Perpendicular to the Magnetic Field, the equation for electric field of an electromagnetic wave propagating perpendicular to an external magnetic field is presented as
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
S & -iD & 0\\
iD & (S - \eta^2)& 0\\
0 & 0 & (P - \eta^2)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
E_x\\
E_y\\
E_z 
\end{bmatrix} = 0
\label{Cold_Matrix_Perp}
\end{equation}
The disperson relationships are of course found by setting the determinant of this matrix to zero. This yeilds
\begin{equation}
    \eta^2 = P
    \label{Ordinary_Dispersion1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \eta^2 = \frac{RL}{S}
\end{equation}
I am okay with the derivation until this point. He then claims that each of these dispersion relationships has an associated electric field eigenvector. The eigenvector of the first relationship is $\mathbf{E} = (0, 0, E_0)$, while the eigenvector of the second is $\mathbf{E} = (\frac{iD}{S}, E_0, 0)$. Where did these eigenvectors come from? How were they derived? The author is not clear on their origin.

It's a linear eigenvalue problem (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) so you can deconstruct the 3x3 tensor into something akin to [A - I * lambda] * u = 0, where lambda are the eigenvalues and u the eigen vectors.  There are a bunch of different techniques to do this (e.g., LU-decomposition... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm for some examples).
